# Django. ImageField. Path to static file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I use Django 1.9.1, Python 3.5.
Code:

```
class Image(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "shop/static/shop")
description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.image.url

def image_tag(self):
    return u'<img src="/%s" width="300"/>' % self.image.url[5:] #Bad code
image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

When object Image is created then `Image.image.url=shop/static/shop/filename`. I can get the image on following address: `/static/shop/filename`. This example is working but

```
return u'<img src="/%s" width="300"/>' % self.image.url[5:] #Bad code
```

`self.image.url[5:]` is bad code I think. If `STATIC_URL` will be changed then the code won't work. How is it possible to change the code for working with other `STATIC_URL`. Does exist a library handling URL?

Comment: Pleeeease indent your code properly. It's hardly readable. And elaborate a bit on what specific goal are you trying to achieve? Do you have your `STATIC_URL` baked in the database records?

Comment: The goal is to write a function which returns **valid** URL of Image. It will be used in templates in `<img>` tag for example. I don't know if my `STATIC_URL` baked in the database records. The `STATIC_URL` is in `settings.py`.

Comment: As far as I know, the url returned by `instance.image.url` is completely valid. More than that, it automatically changes if you change the `settings.STATIC_URL`. Maybe you need something like `manage.py collectstatic` to move your static files to the proper location?

Comment: Static files is serving in `shop/static/shop` (`upload_to` argument). And `instance.image.url` shows __served path + filename__: `shop/static/shop/filename`. This url isn't valid. This is path. Expected valid url is `static/shop/filename`.

Comment: Could you post your settings related to handling static files? All that `settings.STATIC*` variables.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JzZYxw0F This is settings.py

Comment: Oh, wait. I've just realized that you have your images in the models. This changes everything. You should be using the `MEDIA_*` vars instead of `STATIC_*` ones to manage your user-uploaded files. Try setting the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings. Does that help?

Comment: Doesn't work: `The MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL settings must have different values`. If values of `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` are different, for example `MEDIA_URL = '/static2/'` URL has following structure: `/static2/shop/static/shop/filename`. Probably it's simpler to make provide "bydlokod". Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` are for static files - files that are used by your web application and don't change by its users, i.e. static images(you site logo, backgrounds, etc).
If you are using files, that are uploaded by users, images or not, `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` are used.
When you define `upload_to` it is concatenated with `MEDIA_ROOT` in your settings.
So i.e.:

`MEDIA_ROOT='/var/www/media/'`

and you define:

`image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "shop/static/shop")`

the image will be stored as `/var/www/media/shop/static/shop/[image_name.jpg]`.

`MEDIA_URL` is the part in URL that will correspond to `MEDIA_ROOT` on filesystem path.

Also, if by `self.image.url[5:]` you're trying to get relative path, depending on your settings you might be good with using just `self.image.path`.

Comment: i define upload_to = 'test', my media_root /var/www/site, from debugger image.path = /var/www/site/imagename.ext - without upload_to. phisicaly image stored by /var/www/site/text/imagename.ext why?

Comment: @Routhinator Have you read the question and my answer in full or just looked at highlighted things? If you would bother reading it, you would notice, that there's a mention of where to put static files and where to put user uploads. I see no value in your comment the way it is composed.

Comment: @Nikita Sorry I misunderstood the context and have been reading too many questions that don't answer the problem I'm dealing with. I'll remove my comment, however given my comment and the lack of an answer dealing with how to get Django to allow a default file to be in static, I think I'll be opening another question to deal with that issue.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks [Nikita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5738152/nikita)! It helped me. To `settings.py` I added 2 lines:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/1234/5/6/django_app/media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Besides that I changed `models.py`. Before:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'some_path')
```

After:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
```

I.e. images uploaded by a user download to `MEDIA_ROOT` path automatically.

In order to make these images available provide browser, it'd make following changes in `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After that the image will be available in `http://server.com/media/filename_of_image`.

My goal was to show the image in admin control panel. After those manipulations the code in models.py will be following:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url

    def image_tag(self):
        return u'<img src="%s" width="300"/>' % self.image.url #Not bad code
    image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: This was a great help. Thanks. But you don't need to use an explicit path for your MEDIA_URL, if it's within your project structure. This is what I did. MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'djangoapp/media/djangoapp' )
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'